# Hide .php extension in ALL subdirectories with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to hide the .php extensions on my page for all subdirectories with .htaccess.

Currently I have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

It works perfectly fine with normal pages, however any page inside a folder gives me a 500 Internal Service Error. An example URL would be

> http://www.motorcityline.com/portfolio/michigantinting

Which is actually /portfolio/michigantinting.php. The .php file does exist, I just don't have the .htaccess file configured properly.

Comment: Did you bother to search Stack Overflow—or even Google—for this query first?

Comment: ............
Yes? I've spent hours trying different rules, none would work. Isn't that the point of asking the question?

Comment: But just a question : the http://www.motorcityline.com/portfolio/michigantinting.php file really exists ?

Comment: @Smashbox But it’s such a common query which has been answered hundreds of times before that I can’t understand why, if you had searched, you’d have a problem. There’s various solutions on Stack Overflow alone.

Comment: Martin I please ask that you be constructive. There are a couple people helping me currently if you can't see and I am still encountering issues. It's not as simple as "google it". As previously stated, I've implemented the solutions in the topics on stack overflow and had no success. If you have suggestions on the question at hand, I am open to hear them, otherwise, have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your .htaccess with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I really like how that auto removes the .php, however for some strange reason I am getting a 404 on pages that exist. Example being http://www.motorcityline.com/services.php

Comment: As long as above .htaccess is placed in $DOCUMENT_ROOT it will work. Where did you place it?

Comment: It is in the root directory of my hosting plan with GoDaddy. The subdirectories are working with this code, however the .php files in my root directory are giving me a 404

Comment: Hmm weird, try commenting this line: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f` and see if that helps

Comment: Negative ;( When commented I still get a 404 with and additional 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Did you add the mod_rewrite module to your apache configuration?

Comment: Is that all of your .htaccess file or you have something else? Try my edited code now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas Willems, works for /portfolio/michigantinting, however any normal pages now give a 500 error. So for example. "http://motorcityline.com/work" now does not work.

Comment: Almost the same result. I am now getting a 404 with an additional 500 Internal Server Error error. The pages do exist.

Comment: http://motorcityline.com/work.php will work properly, but not /work without the .php